# Varying linespaces

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

I have a problem with linespaces in my document.
Im using the "Book" documentclass.
Here is an example:

[image]

following Code-Snippet produces this Output:

```
Nachdem im Kapitel \ref{sec:PIZR_Buck} und \ref{sec:PIZR_Boost} die Berechnungsvorschriften für die Reglerparameter in Abhängigkeit der Polstellen gefunden wurden, kann nun die Polplatzierung durchgeführt werden.
Eine einheitliche Methode zur Vergabe der Streckenpole ist nicht möglich, weshalb es sich anbietet, vorab günstige Lagen der Polstellen zu definieren.
Allgemein lassen sich Polstellen durch die Eigenfrequenz $\omega_\mathrm{e}$ und die Dämpfung $\zeta$ charakterisieren.
Für ein komplex konjugiertes Polstellenpaar gilt:
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{p}_{1,2} = \omega_\mathrm{e}\left(-\zeta\pm j\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\right),
\end{align}
wobei für eine rein reelle Polstelle mit $\zeta=1$ folgt:
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{p}_{3} = \omega_\mathrm{e} .   
\end{align} 
An der Lage der Pole kann man Systemeigenschaften wie z.B. Kausalität, Stabilität und Dynamik ablesen \cite{Unbehauen_SYS}.
Die zu platzierenden Pole haben einen Einfluss auf das Zeitverhalten einer Eigenbewegung des Systems.
Die Nullstellen des charakteristischen Polynoms einer Differentialgleichung bestimmen die Exponenten der Exponentialfunktion in der allgemeinen Lösung der Differentialgleichung.
```

This type of Error appears at several points in my Work..
What causes this?

EDIT: This are my include and defines:

```
% 00_defines.tex
% ------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[12pt,
              a4paper,
              DIV=calc,openany
            ]{book}%{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\automark[section]{chapter}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
% scrartcl ist eine abgeleitete Artikel-Klasse im Koma-Skript
% zur Kontrolle des Umbruchs Klassenoption draft verwenden
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
%\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{array,cellspace}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage[]{listofsymbols}
%\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{trees}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\def\coord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
\def\coord(#1){node[circle, red, draw, inner sep=1pt,pin={[red, overlay, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\tiny, pin distance=0.1cm, pin edge={red, overlay,}]45:#1}](#1){}}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,decorations.markings,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %-> PDFLATEX
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %  Alternativ unter Windows
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %-> PDFLATEX
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}
\usepackage[]{listofsymbols}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{minted,xcolor}
\usemintedstyle{monokai}
\setminted{fontsize=\scriptsize,baselinestretch=1}
% Abstand obere Blattkante zur Kopfzeile ist 2.54cm - 15mm
\setlength{\topmargin}{-15mm}
\newtheorem{Satz}{Satz}[section]
\newtheorem{Definition}[Satz]{Definition} 
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Satz]{Lemma}                          
%\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\definecolor{tokloGrey}{rgb}{0.68,0.68,0.68}
% Für Zeichnung
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% Schriftgröße der Caption
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize}
\captionsetup[table]{font=footnotesize}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
% Microtype - für gleichbleibende Zeilenumbrüche
\usepackage{microtype}
\definecolor{tkblue}{rgb}{0,0.212,0.369}
\definecolor{tkred}{rgb}{1,0.064,0.064}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{array,cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt} 
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newsavebox\circuiti
\newsavebox\circuitii
\newsavebox\circuitiii
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex
        \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode --extra-mem-top=3000000
        -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
\tikzsetnextfilename{name_of_resulting_pdf}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\newcommand{\stoptocwriting}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}}
\newcommand{\resumetocwriting}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\arabic{tocdepth}}}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{%
  \footnotesize%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{%
  \footnotesize%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{bmatrix}{%
  \footnotesize%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align*}{%
  \footnotesize%
}

% FÜR Matplotlib
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
```

Comment: Any problems are probably caused by something BEFORE this snippet.  Like changing \baselineskip or the font size.

Comment: The picture I inserted is from Site 26. The Beginning of an new section. There are only Equations on previous Sites without \baselineskip, pictures or changing the fontsize.. the page before is normally printed with the right linespace.. so only the part behaves wrong..

Comment: Try \the\baselineskip to search for changes.  If this is the first thing in a new section, look at \section and \@afterheading.  Packages can change book.cls definitions.

Comment: I inserted \the\baselineskip before the first part (the bad part), and the second part.. both equals to 14.5pt

Comment: you should be able to make an example that shows the problem. in a copy of the docment delete everything after this and delete everythig before that you can delete while still showing the issue, then remove all packages not needed in th eresultig small example, then post the complete document here

Comment: adding a list of dozens of packages doesn't help unless that can be used to show the problem, pleas make a complete document and remove every package that you can remove while showing the effect. That makes it much easier for people to run the example with tracing turned on to see what is happening.

Comment: oh skip that. You have `\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{%
  \footnotesize%
}`  don't do that!!!!!!

Comment: please do not edit solutions into the question that makes it impossible for future readers. Your last edit removes the cause of the problem (the`\footnotesize` and just shows some unrelated use of `\input` I suggest you revert that edit.

Comment: Ok! I have re-edit it-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since this answer was published the question was clarified

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{%
  \footnotesize%
}
```

this will cause the paragraph before the alignment to be set with normalsize text on a footnotesize baseline, as the paragarph is set with the settings in force at the end of the paragraph.

A minimal example is
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\zzalign\align
\def\align{\footnotesize\zzalign} % Dont do this

\begin{document}

\section{zzz\label{sec:PIZR_Buck}}
zz
\section{zzz\label{sec:PIZR_Boost}}


Nachdem im Kapitel \ref{sec:PIZR_Buck} und \ref{sec:PIZR_Boost} die
Berechnungsvorschriften für die Reglerparameter in Abhängigkeit der
Polstellen gefunden wurden, kann nun die Polplatzierung durchgeführt
werden.  Eine einheitliche Methode zur Vergabe der Streckenpole ist
nicht möglich, weshalb es sich anbietet, vorab günstige Lagen der
Polstellen zu definieren.  Allgemein lassen sich Polstellen durch die
Eigenfrequenz $\omega_\mathrm{e}$ und die Dämpfung $\zeta$
charakterisieren.  Für ein komplex konjugiertes Polstellenpaar gilt:
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{p}_{1,2} = \omega_\mathrm{e}\left(-\zeta\pm j\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\right),
\end{align}
wobei für eine rein reelle Polstelle mit $\zeta=1$ folgt:
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{p}_{3} = \omega_\mathrm{e} .   
\end{align} 
An der Lage der Pole kann man Systemeigenschaften wie z.B. Kausalität,
Stabilität und Dynamik ablesen \cite{Unbehauen_SYS}.  Die zu
platzierenden Pole haben einen Einfluss auf das Zeitverhalten einer
Eigenbewegung des Systems.  Die Nullstellen des charakteristischen
Polynoms einer Differentialgleichung bestimmen die Exponenten der
Exponentialfunktion in der allgemeinen Lösung der
Differentialgleichung.

\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

From your image it appears you have something equivalent to this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\zzalign\align
\def\align{{\offinterlineskip\par}\zzalign}

\begin{document}

\section{zzz\label{sec:PIZR_Buck}}
zz
\section{zzz\label{sec:PIZR_Boost}}


Nachdem im Kapitel \ref{sec:PIZR_Buck} und \ref{sec:PIZR_Boost} die
Berechnungsvorschriften für die Reglerparameter in Abhängigkeit der
Polstellen gefunden wurden, kann nun die Polplatzierung durchgeführt
werden.  Eine einheitliche Methode zur Vergabe der Streckenpole ist
nicht möglich, weshalb es sich anbietet, vorab günstige Lagen der
Polstellen zu definieren.  Allgemein lassen sich Polstellen durch die
Eigenfrequenz $\omega_\mathrm{e}$ und die Dämpfung $\zeta$
charakterisieren.  Für ein komplex konjugiertes Polstellenpaar gilt:
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{p}_{1,2} = \omega_\mathrm{e}\left(-\zeta\pm j\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\right),
\end{align}
wobei für eine rein reelle Polstelle mit $\zeta=1$ folgt:
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{p}_{3} = \omega_\mathrm{e} .   
\end{align} 
An der Lage der Pole kann man Systemeigenschaften wie z.B. Kausalität,
Stabilität und Dynamik ablesen \cite{Unbehauen_SYS}.  Die zu
platzierenden Pole haben einen Einfluss auf das Zeitverhalten einer
Eigenbewegung des Systems.  Die Nullstellen des charakteristischen
Polynoms einer Differentialgleichung bestimmen die Exponenten der
Exponentialfunktion in der allgemeinen Lösung der
Differentialgleichung.

\end{document}
```

But it is hard to guess the intent of the code as in this form it doesn't do anything other than explicitly mess up the line spacing.

---

Comment: Ok thanks! But how do I get my align/equation/bmatrix enviroments smaller and holding the linespaces constant? Its not that pretty to have such big equations..

Comment: @adaptive the simplest thing would be to put `\par` before `\footnotesize` although this will mess up the vertical spacing, but the document will not look publication quality with all the math shrunk in this way, so perhaps some white space issues don't matter.

Comment: If i do that: \AtBeginEnviroment{align}{\par\footnotesize} I get a lot of "Missing $" errors in my equations

Comment: @adaptive ah the etoolbox hook must be adding the code not quite at the right place. out of time now I'll look later (or try `\endgraf` instead of `\par`)

Comment: @adaptive but I would never make all display math footnote size, if you want to shringk a specific matrix do `\mbox{\footnotesize$\begin{matrix}.....\end{matrix}}`

Comment: @adaptive -- The `\par` has to go *before* the `align`.  This will unfortunately have the result that the vertical space above the `align` is larger than desired, and also that a page break will be permitted between the text and the `align`.  A negative `\vspace` can patch up the first problem, but suppressing the break is a bit harder.  David should be able to help with this.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ive tried the \mbox{...} locally on one Matrix, but It dont work.. I would prefer to redefine the align/bmatrix/equation enviroment instead of editing every enviroment in my whole document..

Comment: @adaptive using the form in this answer, but with `\par\footnotesize` does what you want. (but I wouldn't do it)